# What synthetic types are defined by scala language?

Tags: scala, types

There is Any, AnyVal (AnyRef is just a type alias), Unit, Null, Nothing, Singleton. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples you might be looking for this diagram

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/unified-types.html

Comment: `scala.Singleton` does exist. Every Singleton object automatically extends it. See http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#singleton-types (though the spec is rather vague about it).

Comment: Didn't know that, thank you. `val o: Singleton = SomeSingletonObject` works indeed, although I cannot find any occurrence of word `Singleton` in scala sources, any idea where is it defined?

Comment: That diagram I know :) However, recently I have encountered Singleton and wondered if there are any more I didn't know about. Singleton is a purely synthetic type, it is not an extended trait; rather, o.type <: Singleton for any object o, similarly as (t :T).Member <: T#Member, and it is useful exactly in that context. By requiring that T<:Singleton, I know that the above two types are always equal, which would otherwise require synthetic casting.